# Why is this wrong? Convergence proof using definition

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I missed this question on a test and I can't figure out what I did wrong. I tried asking and was told that I messed up the algebra but then I went home tried it again and got the same answer.
The question is
$$\text{Find } \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n-2}{n+9}. \text{What is the smallest integer N when } \epsilon = 0.5 $$

Here is my scratchwork:
$$\left| \frac{2n-2}{n+9} - \frac{2(n+9)}{n+9} \right| = \left| \frac{2n-2-2n-9}{n+9} \right| = \left| \frac{-11}{n+9} \right| = \frac{11}{n+9}$$

For the proof portion I set $N = \lceil 11/\epsilon \rceil$ (since $\frac{11}{n+9} < \frac{11}{n} < \epsilon $) which was marked correctly but then for the smallest integer I plugged in $\epsilon = 0.5$ into $\frac{11}{\epsilon}-9 = \frac{11}{1/2} - 9 = 22-9 = 13$. So I concluded that the smallest $N = 13$. This is the portion that was marked incorrectly and I'm not sure why aside from that it may have been unclear since I suddenly added the 9 back in? I can't see it so I'm hoping someone here can tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: For a start, $2(n+9)$ equals $2n+18$ not $2n+9$.

Comment: You should ask your professor.

Comment: $\epsilon$ should be arbitrary. You should not be plugging in a value for it.

Comment: "What is the smallest integer $N$ when $\epsilon=0.5?$" is incomprehensible, since neither $N$ nor $\epsilon$ has a referrent. Have you written out the full question, word-for-word?

Comment: @Stat, I *think* OP is being told $\epsilon=0.5$, and is being asked to find $N$ (but OP should clarify this).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah ok I see.

Comment: In problems like this it is not necessary to find the smallest $N\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that  $n>N\implies 11/(n+9)<\epsilon.$ It suffices to find  some such $N. $ Short cuts based on crude bounds  can keep you out of trouble. For example,  $0<1/(n+9)<1/n$ when $ n\in \Bbb Z^+,$ so if $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and $n>11/\epsilon >0$ then $0<11/(n+9)<11/n<\epsilon.$

Comment: Any thoguhts on the comments, password?

Comment: Are you still here, password?